# Wikimedia template failing to render reference properly

Tags: mediawiki-templates, wikimedia

I have a template called "problem" with the following definition:

```
⚠️<ref>⚠️ {{{1}}}</ref>
```

The intent is to use it like so: `{{problem|Describe the problem here.}}` and have the description appear in the `<references>` section.

What's actually rendering for each reference: `↑ ⚠️ {{{1}}}`. (The interstitial text is rendering correctly.)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [special case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Template#Handling_parameters) in which the parameter `{{{1}}}` is not expanded. To solve this, need to use the `{{#tag:}}` parser function. Just replace the content of your template with this:

```
⚠️{{#tag:ref|⚠️ {{{1}}}}}
```